# kivy error 1114 in windows 10

Tags: installation, kivy

I have installed kivy and pygame but when I run a kivy code I get an error. The exact error is as below:

```
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC 
v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif 
(img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
```

A separate dialogue box opens and it gives the following message: 
Loadlibrary failed with error 1114. A dynamic link library(DLL) initialization route failed.

I have tried many solutions in the internet such as maximizing performance of switchable graphics and reinstalling but the problem still exists. Please inform me on what is the problem and how to rectify it.

Comment: 1/ there is no error in this log, please run kivy with log level to at least "debug" (see kivy config file) 2/ please describe how you installed kivy on your computer, 3/ please provide a capture of the error.

Comment: I followed the instructions in the kivy website to install. I typed the commands in my command prompt. I reinstalled again and checked it today. It is working now. I think the problem might have been with my graphics properties.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too.

All I did was change the BATTERY PERFORMANCE to MAXIMUM performance in my graphics properties.

It works fine now.